# python xml parse with minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I have this XML file 
and I need to read the value from Sync and Event in the same order as in the XML file.

```
<Episode>
<Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="263.035">
    <Turn startTime="0" endTime="4.844" speaker="spk1">
        <Sync time="0"/>
        aaaaa
    </Turn>
    <Turn speaker="spk2" startTime="4.844" endTime="15.531">
        <Sync time="4.844"/>
        bbbbb
        <Event desc="poz" type="noise" extent="begin"/>
        ccccc
        <Event desc="poz" type="noise" extent="end"/>
        ddddd

    <Sync time="12.210"/>
        eeeee 
    </Turn>
    <Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="15.531" endTime="17.549">
        <Event desc="poz" type="noise" extent="begin"/>
        fffff
    </Turn>
</Section>
</Episode>
```

And I need this output:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```

Is there any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the minidom? The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom) warns against using it (the DOM is way to verbose and archaic) and recommends you use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin sax parser:

```
from xml import sax

class EpisodeContentHandler(sax.ContentHandler):
    def characters(self, content):
        content = content.strip()
        if content:
            print content

with open("Episode.xml") as f:
    sax.parse(f, EpisodeContentHandler())
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're somehow limited to using Minidom, try using 'ElementTree' as Martijn suggested. From my personal experience, it's much easier to use. You can find it's documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)

For your problem, you can try something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Get the tree structure of the XML
tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
# Get the root/first tag in the tree
root = tree.getroot()
# Ge all elements with interesting tags
for child in root.findall("Sync"):
   print child.text
```

Sidenote: `child.attrib` is a map to all the tag's attributes.

Comment: Thank you, but this code doesn´t work. Is there any way to do it with minidom? Or I have to use ElementTree...

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using minidom:

```
elements = minidom.parseString(xml).getElementsByTagName('*') # where xml is your input xml
for el in elements:
    if el.localName == 'Sync' or el.localName == 'Event':
        print el.nextSibling.nodeValue.strip()
```

This will print:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```